# Retrieving data from listbox to a range

Tags: vba

I have a code which displays a non contiguous range from range (A1:E10) in a userform listbox

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:E10")

With ListBox1
  .ColumnCount = 3
  .ColumnWidths = "100;100,100"
  ' load 1st, 3rd and 5th columns of range (A,C and E) into listbox
  .List = Application.Index(rng, Evaluate("ROW(1:" & rng.Rows.Count & ")"), Array(1, 3,5))
End With
End Sub
```

Now I need a click button code to retrieve back any selected row in the listbox to another range (G1:I1)

Answer (score 1):

Assign the following macro to that button.I am considering your listbox as a form control.
 In case of activeX control replace **.ListBoxes("ListBox1")** with **.ListBox1** and start loop from **0** to **.ListCount-1** .

```
 Sub Test()

        Dim lngLoop         As Long
        Dim strValue        As String

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            With .ListBoxes("ListBox1")
                For lngLoop = 1 To .ListCount
                    If .Selected(lngLoop) Then
                        strValue = strValue & "|" & .List(lngLoop)
                    End If
                Next
           End With
           .Range("G1:I1") = Split(Mid(strValue, 2), "|")
        End With

    End Sub
```